# GetSQS NiFi receive messages filtered based on content

Tags: apache-nifi, amazon-sqs

I am using GetSQS processor to consume messages from a queue. Instead of getting all the messages, is there a way to get only messages that have a specific string in the content?

Do I have to get all the messages and do the filtering on my side, or is there a property we can set on the queue URL, or another attribute that can be sent as part of the GetSQS request to the server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to filter SQS Message by content at the SQS level.

If you want to filter messages by their content, you will need to consume the messages first and then do the filtering.

This is quite simple to do in NiFi, with several different options.

First, consume the messages with [GetSQS](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-aws-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.aws.sqs.GetSQS/index.html).

If you just want to work with raw text, you could then filter with [RouteOnContent](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.RouteOnContent/).

If you want to work with structured text, like JSON or XML which are supported by SQS, you could use [QueryRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryRecord/index.html) with a [JSON](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.json.JsonTreeReader/index.html) or [XML](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.xml.XMLReader/index.html) Reader.